# C++: static array inside class having unknown size

Tags: c++, arrays, static-members, data-members

I wasn't familiar with this. I searched it on google but didn't find my answer. So, posting my question.
Just tried following program:

```
#include <iostream>
class test
{
    static char a[];
    static int b[];
};
int main()
{
    test t;
}
```

It compiles fine without any warnings on MSVS 2010 & g++ 4.8.1. It also compiles fine in C++14 compiler. (See live demo [here.](http://ideone.com/efyI6c)) So, where does C++ standard says about this? If I remove static keyword from the declaration of char array in test class, compiler gives an error `ISO C++ forbids zero size array` when I use `-pedantic-errors` command line option in g++ & `/Za`option in MSVS 2010 compiler it says `error C2133: 'test::a' : unknown size`. So, my questions are:

1) what is the use of unknown size static array?

2) How do I later specify size of them & access that array elements? I am really getting confused.

3) Why removing static keyword leads to compilation errors?

It would be better if someone would explain it using simple example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler doesn't care about the size. It's just a declaration for the static field, so telling it you have an array is enough. Size doesn't matter at this point.

You only have a declaration for the static field at this point. You never use those arrays and the compiler is permissive... it won't complain.

If you want to use them however, you'll need a *definition*. If you omit the size there, you'll get similar error messages you saw before.

There isn't anything special going on.

Comment: Why removing static keyword leads to compiler error?

Comment: Because it's a definition for the *class*. In C++ all object has to have a known size.